# Wordpress get_results on non-object error

Tags: php, wordpress, object

I want to get the records using this query, but i am getting this error while fetching the records from the database...

**Code is:**

```
public function AddStartupValue($sID,$cID,$serverType)
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $qryVal = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `price` FROM `wp_calculator_products` WHERE `sID` = ".$sID." AND `cID` = ".$cID." AND `serverType` = '".$serverType."'", OBJECT);
        return $qryVal;
    }
```

**The error i am getting is :**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object
```

I am also unable to print_r($wpdb), its providing empty result..

Let me know how we can solve this issue..
Regards,

Comment: are you sure you're calling this function after the db is initialized? (using a wp hook or something)

Comment: yes, because $wpdb is working for all above functins but not this functio... it is called when we click on button through ajax..

Comment: and in the ajax handler, you're loading the whole wordpress system?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include `config.php` file if not included:

```
require_once('../../../config.php');
```

Comment: But its working for other queries inside a class.. just specifically not applying on this function, i don't know why...:(

Comment: Are you overwritting value of $wpdb?

Answer (score -1):

i think you have to global $wpdb on the top for the file not in the public function .

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

In your case  query() is associated with the get_results() method of $wpdb class object.